# Do idolaters pray to God?

Tags: sources-mekorot, avodah-zarah

A long time ago I read that our Sources say, "It is forbidden to disturb an idolater praying to his idols because, although he does not know it, he is praying to God." Is this accurate and what is the reference?

*Edit*:. I found my source: The 1928 book "Pourquoi je suis juif" (Why I am a Jew), by French writer Edmond Fleg, who attributes it to the Talmud. No exact reference is given.

Comment: I’d imagine this depends on the kind of idol worship. If one believes this rock is his god, I can’t imagine this would be the case. If one believes that serving this rock is a way of serving the One G-d, maybe I could hear this argument. Maybe.